# How to combine AddressSanitizer with dynamically linked Pthreads library?

Tags: c, gcc, x86-64, dynamic-linking, address-sanitizer

I am trying to use *AddressSanitizer* for a program that is multi threaded and uses pthread library functions. However instead of statically linking with `-lpthread` flag during compilation with gcc, I am using dynamic link `-ldl -rdynamic $filename.so` which provides implementation of pthread functions. I have read that AddressSanitizer should be the first linked library, so I added it like this:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libasan.so
```

The problem I have is that while executing the program, it gets stuck at pthread_create. As I understand because this function is not provided statically, it's looked for in dynamically linked libraries, in `libasan.so` first and it gets blocked there, not moving to the second library that actually contains implementation of pthread_create function. 
I also tried using `-fsanitize=address (with -lasan)` to link with AddressSanitizer during compilation but I got the same result.

Is there anything else I could try to make these two libraries work together?

Comment: Does your library provide a custom implementation Pthreads? It would help if you could precisely specify how you link executable and the other shared library.

Comment: @yugr yes, it does. in Makefile I used this: LDFLAGS   =  -ldl -rdynamic $NVthreads/src/libnvthread.so. Before, with static linking I had this: LDFLAGS   = -lpthread. Without AddressSanitizer this dynamic linking works fine so it implements all the pthread library functions I use.